# Transfer JSON string data on a C# Server via Web Socket Network

Tags: javascript, c#, json, websocket, kinect

Currently the client is sending the data to the server but on the same computer I want the client to send this data to the server on another computer. Is there a way this can be done? I have attached the client and server side of the code that sends and receives the data. I want the  client to send the data to a C# server on a different computer using Web Sockets but it only sends the data if both the server and client are on the same computer.

Server Code:

```
private static void bodyFrameReader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool dataReceived = false;

        using (BodyFrame bodyFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (bodyFrame != null)
            {
                if (bodies == null)
                {
                    bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];

                }
                bodyFrame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(bodies);
                dataReceived = true;
            }
        }

        if (dataReceived)
        {

            foreach (var client in clients)
            {

                var users = bodies.Where(s => s.IsTracked.Equals(true)).ToList();

                if (users.Count>0){
                    string json = users.Serialize(_coordinateMapper, _mode);

                    Console.WriteLine("jsonstring: " + json);
                    Console.WriteLine("After body serialization and to send");

                    client.Send(json);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Client Code below:

```
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181");

    socket.onopen = function (event) {
        label.innerHTML = "Connection open";
    }


    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        if (typeof event.data === "string") {

            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(event.data);

            console.log("Json Arrived");


            for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.skeletons.length; i++) { 

                for (var j = 0; j < jsonObject.skeletons[i].joints.length; j++) {
                    var joint = jsonObject.skeletons[i].joints[j];

                }
            }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYnwW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, where you have `var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181");`

Try changing it to `var socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.XXX.XXX.XXX");` Where `192.XXX.XXX.XXX` is the ip address of the other computer you want to send the data to.

`Localhost` means own computer essentially. Hope this helped!